# Mini mind reader

Tags: c

Here is a code that guesses the number chosen by the user. I know that using goto is a bad practice, but it seems unavoidable here.

that's because using `do while` doesn't work, for example:

```
do{
   scanf("%c",&variable);
  }while(variable == 'a' || variable = 'b' || variable = 'c');
```

would accept all letters while I want it to accept only a,b and c, so I think using `if/else` and `goto` is better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
int main()
{
    int guess;
    int tries=0;
    char answer;
    answer='y';
    int min =0;
    int max = 101;
    int avg;
    int a =0;
    int i,j;

puts("pick a number between 1 and 100");
puts("if the number is higher than the guess press h");
puts("if it is less than the guess press l ");
puts("if my guess is correct press y");


    for(i=0; (i< 8); i++)
        {
         sleep(600);
         avg = (min + max)/2;
         if(!avg)
         break;

         printf("is it %d\?\n", avg );
        fff:
        answer = getchar();



        if(answer == 'y')
        {
            a++;
            break;
        }
        else if(answer == 'h')
        {
            min = avg;
        }
        else if(answer == 'l')
        {
            max = avg;

        }
        else
        goto fff;
        }


        int sol = rand() % 4 + 1;
        if(a)
        {

            switch(sol)
            {


                case 2: puts("You are not good enough to beat me, human");
                        break;

                case 3: puts("Stop wasting my time, your numbers are so easy to guess");
                        break;
                case 4: puts("Next");
                        break;
                //case 1:
                default:

                        printf("That was easy your number is : %d ", avg);
                        break;



            }


        }
        else
        {
            xa:
            switch(sol)
            {
                case 2:
                        puts("Are you sure about this number");
                        break;

                case 3: puts("I don't support imaginary numbers");
                        break;
                case 4: puts("Stop playing with me");
                break;

                //case 1:
                default:
                        puts("I think there is no such number");
            }

        }
        sleep(2000);
        getchar();

       return 0;


}
```

Comment: If `goto` is inevitable, a label named `fff:` has to be ;)

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that will make answers look invalid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bad things happen when you use use GOTO.....

[image: Velociraptor]

The problem with your while loop is that you are using `=` instead of `==` .... you are assigning the values to the variable inside the loop, and it is successful, thus accepts all characters......

> ```
> do{
>    scanf("%c",&variable);
>   }while(variable == 'a' || variable = 'b' || variable = 'c');
> ```

Fix it....

```
  do{
   scanf("%c",&variable);
  }while(variable == 'a' || variable == 'b' || variable == 'c');
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, the do-while loop may not be the best it needs to be bigger.... consider the following:

```
int ok = 1;

do
{
    printf("is it %d\?\n", avg );
    answer = getchar();
    if(answer == 'y')
    {
        a++;
        ok = 1;
        break;
    }
    else if(answer == 'h')
    {
        ok = 1;
        min = avg;
    }
    else if(answer == 'l')
    {
        ok = 1;
        max = avg;
    }
    else
    {
        ok = 0;
        printf("Illegal input %c\n", answer);
    }
} while (!ok)
```

Comment: @nathan - edited answer with decent loop.

Comment: Get back to your Java world! ;)